# How to utilize my learning power in ASP.NET studies?

Tags: asp.net

I've recently tried to switch to ASP.NET. Did I write switch? I meant to learn it, however I am not really sure how to proceed. I've opened several videos - and really watched them with enthusiasm however they seem to be very general. It's not like there are tons of sources on learning PHP.

**Do you know some great learning procedure including the websites and sources to learn from so I can learn it ASAP?**

I got one project waiting here -> the website is kinda simple Online flash games. The graphics and HTML's finished but I want to try to do it in ASP.NET with MS SQL. I'm already experienced in C# thus I won't need a lot of insight into that, although I'm absolutely unaware of how to do the website, cute urls, what the basic principles in coding are etc..etc.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a PHP background, I'd recommend that you try out [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) - if you are familiar with the MVC design pattern, it should be a rather painless 'switch'. The ["Learn ASP.NET MVC"](http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/) section is very nice. There's also an RSS feed (on the site above) that contains many great blog posts regarding the technology; furthermore, there's the NerdDinner sample website with a [complete tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm). If you follow the last one, you should be ready with the site in no time :)

Comment: I agree that the ASP.NET MVC tutorial chapter is a great place to start as it builds a complete (albeit simple) website from scratch, step-by-step.  I'd also recommend the *ASP.NET 2.0 Website Programming - Problem Design Solution* book (http://www.amazon.com/ASP-NET-2-0-Website-Programming-Programmer/dp/0764584642/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1249458380&sr=1-5) which also does a similar thing.  The entire book builds a complete website, step by step, and is a great way to *"bring it all together"*

Comment: Does it mean I should start developing in MVC only?

Comment: Well I guess it depends on whom you ask :) MVC encourages best practices such as test-driven development and separates responsibility, and WebForms allows a component-driven structure.
The .NET framework behind them is the same, but the concepts are different. Currently, there is the separation that MVC is used for public sites (e.g. StackOverflow) and WebForms are used for web applications (e.g. a corporate site for vehicle management or so).

Answer (score 0):

I have found these Microsoft videos to be very useful as study material. [Videos](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/)